# How to integrate metronic theme with DNN9?

Tags: themes, dotnetnuke-9, metronic

We have a DNN9 platform for our Business2Business website. It has basic look of reports however we wanted to show some advance look to reports and charts so that we are planning to integrate metronic theme in DNN9. I tried multiple ways to do it but failed. kindly help regarding this for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried but we succeeded in displaying reports module data using Mandeeps Porto css and boostrap classes.

We achieved this using the xsl stylesheet option in reports module settings.

If the theme resources are part of your portal skin on the page that the reports module resides then xsl elements will display fine. If not part of the portal theme, you can either declare the resource in page setting header or in the xsl stylesheet itself.

Hope this helps